# Navicat Merge Command, terminator dropped

Tags: sql, navicat

Using *Navicat*, I am running an SQL Merge Command, Navicat seems to drop off the `;` from the end of the command, causing it to fail.

I can't find a way to change the terminator character to something like `#`.

Answer (score 0):

well, I kinda gave up on it. :-)  I just put it in a Stored Procedure - works fine, but I was hoping to find a "query" fix.